# No yellow highlight in VS Code's Disassembly View while debugging C++ on MacOS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging, lldb, disassembly

Debugging C++ in VSCode on MacOS works perfectly fine and when I hit "Open Disassembly View" by right-clicking the line the debugger's on (highlighted in yellow with an arrow of the same color), VS Code does open the Disassembly View, but I have no indication as to where the debugger is. Even when I step-over, there is no change in the disassembly view, only the main.cpp file.
I have got three files: 
main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "log.h"

int main()
{
    int x=6;
    bool comparisionResult = x == 5;
    if (comparisionResult)
    {
        Log("Hello, World!");
    }
    std::cin.get();
}
```

log.cpp

```cpp
#include "log.h"

#include <iostream>

void Log(const char* message)
{
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
```

log.h

```cpp
#pragma once

void Log(const char* message);
```

My launch.json looks like this:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please let me know if any more information is needed to figure out the issue. I'm new to debugging and the language. Thanks!